# Read $_SESSION in an external file

Tags: php, html, session

So, suppose I have a php file named A like this:

```
<?php
$_SESSION["Ad gloriam"] = "La musique donne une âme à nos coeurs et des ailes à la pensée.";
?>
    <h4> Hello, everything goes OK<h4>
    <h4> The $_SESSION["Ad gloriam"] = <?php
        echo ($_SESSION["Ad gloriam"]);
    ?></h4>
<script src="/php2.php">
</script>
```

The result looks to something like this:

[image]

---

Now, suppose we have a `/php2.php` file witch I have load in A:

```
<?php
    echo ("console.log ('".$_SESSION["Ad gloriam"]."');");
    echo ("console.log ('Si la vertu ne suffit pas à assurer le bonheur, la méchanceté suffit à rendre malheureux.');");
?>
```

Normally, the script will be execute when I load A and I will see in the `console`:

- `La musique donne une âme à nos coeurs et des ailes à la pensée.` (=> from `$_SESSION["Ad gloriam"]`);
- `Si la vertu ne suffit pas à assurer le bonheur, la méchanceté suffit à rendre malheureux.` (=> a test).

---

However, `$_SESSION["Ad gloriam"]` returns nothing and I do not see anything in the `console`.

What did I wrong?

I do not find anything about the subject in the web. Maybe, I do not achieve to put a name on this error.

**NOTE:** *My title is, maybe, not very clear. Tell me a better title in the comments if you find one, please.*

*Tell me if you have some questions.*

Answer (score 2):

Each php file needs to start a session.

Just add

```
session_start();
```

to each file as first line.